# Javascript Redirects with Pound not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect

I have a link to my site on a very popular but now dead website.  The link is incorrect, so I'd like to redirect users to the correct page when they visit.  I'm using Wordpress for my content.

The problems lie in the fact that the incorrect URL that the website lists is `http://www.senntenial.com/#!mysterium/cj6d` .  From my research, I cannot do a 301 redirect in my htaccess, since this URL has a `#` sign, and is client only.

So, I tried creating the following script in my `header.php` file.

```
if (window.location == 'http://www.senntenial.com/#!mysterium/cj6d'){
    window.location = 'http://www.senntenial.com/mysterium/';
}
```

I would think this would have worked, but it doesn't.  To identify the problem, I tried simply inputting `window.location = 'http://www.senntenial.com/mysterium/';` Which worked correctly, meaning my problem lies in identifying the current window location.

How can I accomplish this?  I assume Wordpress has a funky way of going about things with URL's to make them easier to read that may be messing with my code.

(PS, I tried WP extensions like EPS 301 redirect to no avail.)

Also, the mysterium page is static HTML, and not involved with Wordpress' CMS.

Comment: Is **mysterium** a page or a category/taxonomy? What are your permalinks set to? Give us some more info and maybe we can help out.

Comment: Ah, sorry!  I should have mentioned that mysterium is a static page that isn't using Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `window.location.hash` which gives the fragment part of the current URI. So something like

```
if(window.location.hash=="#!mysterium/cj6d"){
  window.location = 'http://www.senntenial.com/mysterium/';
}
```

Might work. You could also use `window.location.href` which contains the full URI but then you need to check with and without `www.`

Comment: That worked fantastically!  I'll award you the bounty in 7 hours when it unlocks.  Thanks much.